# How can I persist localstorage when ComponentDidMount resets the value on refresh?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, local-storage

I am appending an item to each array item when fetching from a list and setting it to zero.
Then running the function in ComponentDidMount().

```
newsList = (category) => {
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        var news = response.articles;
        news = news.map((x) => ({ ...x, likes: 0 }));
    
          this.setState({ general: news }, () => {
            localStorage.setItem("general", JSON.stringify(this.state.general));
          });
      });
  };
```

I am subsequently incrementing the 'like' value I appended and saving to local storage.

```
generalLikeCount = (x) => {
    let newArr = [...this.state.general];
    newArr[x]["likes"] = parseInt(newArr[x]["likes"]) + 1;
    this.setState({ general: newArr }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem("general", JSON.stringify(this.state.general));
    });
  };
```

But on every refresh, likes counter is reset to zero. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: So why are you overwriting it if it exists?

Comment: Ideally the news items backend should be changed to also store the like-values, and then you can store and retrieve them along with the articles. If the news items backend is readonly for you then you'll have to add some persistent storage elsewhere, outside of the browser, and then combine articles from the news source with the likes from the other source.

Comment: could you share a bit more info ...

1. what causes your refresh? new news data? user interaction?
2. which counter value is reset? the state or local storeage or both?
3. why do you need to save a duplicate of your component state in local storage?
4. can you share the whole component code as well?

Thanks

Comment: @goodmorningasif a manual refresh resets the local storage value to 0. 
2. The likes value in state and storage is reset to zero. 3. I need it to save to local storage so it persists even upon refresh and to state so I can update it on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue, I fixed this by checking if the value exists in local storage and using that value instead, or initializing it if it doesn't exist.

Like so:

```
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(category)) !== null || undefined ) {
          news = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(category));
        } else {
          news = news.map((x) => ({ ...x, likes: 0 }));
        }
```